# Postgres database setup on Cloud9 asks for sudo password

Tags: postgresql, sudo, psql, cloud9-ide

So I'm using the [Cloud9 ide](http://c9.io) to collaborate on a Node.js project. We are using Postgresql for the database, and [the documentation for Postgres](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_postgresql.html) seems to make it quite simple. I can `sudo service postgresql start` without a problem but I can't `sudo -u postgres psql` without it asking for my password, which I don't know because Cloud9 set up the environment for me. Any fixes or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of running `sudo -u postgres psql` try running `sudo sudo -u postgres psql` and you'll get right in. The documentation previously noted this but was recently changed. It will soon be reverted.

Comment: Well, that's odd. Works though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the UNIX account "postgres" is locked, which means it cannot be logged in using a password. See [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install/325596#325596) for complete explanation.

Also try `sudo -s` to open a shell as root and tweak your system.

Comment: Right, it is a bad idea to use sudo passwd postgres, but in the Cloud9 terminal you are logged as 'ubuntu', and I don't know that ubuntu's password, so I can't use his recommendations. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Try `sudo -s` to open a shell as root